# ES6 Setters | error TS2300: Duplicate identifier

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, setter

I am currently writing a class for an Angular 2 component that is using Input/Output decorators and a setter like so:

```
export class ItemDetails {

    // Assign our `item` to a locally scoped property
    @Input('item') _item: Item;
    originalName: string;
    selectedItem: Item;

    // Allow the user to save/delete an item or cancel the
    // operation. Flow events up from here.
    @Output() saved = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() cancelled = new EventEmitter();

    // Perform additional logic on every update via ES6 setter
    // Create a copy of `_item` and assign it to `this.selectedItem`
    // which we will use to bind our form to
    set _item(value: Item) {

        if (value) this.originalName = value.name;
          this.selectedItem = Object.assign({}, value);
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure unless I missed something that this code should be fine, yet I get the error:

```
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier '_item'
```

Any insight as to why this is would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish what I was trying to do, this revised class works fine:

```
export class ItemDetails {

    @Input('item') set _item(value: Item) {

        if (value) this.originalName = value.name;
          this.selectedItem = Object.assign({}, value);
    }
    originalName: string;
    selectedItem: Item;

    @Output() saved = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() cancelled = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A setter doesn't attach onto an existing property, it is its own class member - you can't define `_item` and then name a setter the same thing.